# Cannot launch applications after switching desktop environment to Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments, crash

I recently switched from Unity to Gnome 3 by installing the Gnome Shell. But now when I try to launch certain applications (Eg. PyCharm) they crash with a message

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module"

But certain application like Nautilus will launch in-spite of the error. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install topmenu-gtk?
```

Will install both versions for GTK2 and GTK3.